# Openlayers 3: Get "undefined" for geojson property in one layer

Tags: properties, openlayers-3, geojson

I try to get the property `"SCHULNAME"` from a geojson file.

Here is a snippet from the geojson file:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",

"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},

"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"spatial_name":"01A01",
    "spatial_alias":"1. Schulpraktisches Seminar (S) Mitte",
    "spatial_type":"Point",
    "SCHULNAME":"1. Schulpraktisches Seminar (S) Mitte",
    "SCHULART":"Schulpraktisches Seminar",
    "TRAEGER":"Bezirk",
    "ZWEIG_01":"Schulpraktisches Seminar",
    "ZWEIG_02":null,
    "ZWEIG_03":null,
    "ZWEIG_04":null,
    "BEZIRK":"Mitte",
    "ORTSTEIL":"Wedding",
    "PLZ":"13353",
    "ADRESSE":"Tegeler Str. 16",
    "TELEFON":"4677779713",
    "FAX":"4677779720",
    "EMAIL":"<a href=\"mailto:1.sps-mitte@gmx.de\">1.sps-mitte@gmx.de</a>",
    "INTERNET":null,"LEITUNG":null},
"geometry":{"type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[13.35812948892163,52.54071751171907]}},...
```

Here is the function to open a popup window with the properties:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
              function(feature, layer) {
                return feature;
              });
    if (feature) {
    var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    var printCoord = ol.proj.transform(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates(), 'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326');
    var printProps = feature.getProperties();
    PopupContent.innerHTML =    '<table style="width:100%">'+
                                '<tr>' + '<td>'+'<b>Coordinates:</b> ' + Math.round( printCoord[1] * 100 ) / 100 + 'N, ' + Math.round( printCoord[0] * 100 ) / 100 +'E' +'</td>'+'</tr>'+
                                '<tr>'+'<td>'+"<b>Name:</b> " +printProps.SCHULNAME+'</td>'+'</tr>'+
                                '</table>';
    Popup.setPosition(coordinate);


    }});
```

The coordinates are displayed correctly. For the property `"SCHULNAME"` I get the result `undefined`. However, if I use the same code for the following geojson file and its property `"name"` it works perfectly:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"Mitte",
    "description":"",
    "cartodb_id":1,
    "created_at":"2013-09-03T12:32:04+0200",
    "updated_at":"2013-09-03T12:32:04+0200"},
"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates":[[[[13.403528,52.540212], ...
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you certain that you are getting the expected feature?

Comment: As I stated before: The coordinates are displayed correctly. So I am pretty sure to get the expected feature.

Comment: @user3725485 bit the coordinates are just the coordinates of the click event. Might there be some other feature that is close enough for a match?

Comment: @Alvin Lindstam No. I mean the coordinates in the created html file, not of the position of the popup. You mean 'var coordinate', but the coordinates of the feature I get with 'var printCoord'

Comment: Ah, yes. How do you transform the GeoJSON to ol features? Are there any values in the feature's properties?

Comment: I don't transform GeoJSON to ol features. And for the variable "printProps" I get [object Object]

Comment: You do, but I'm guessing that it's done implicitly by openlayers (if you use your GeoJSON source as an url for ol.source.Vector). I'd suggest learning to use your browsers developer tools, to check the real contents of the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the reason to the problem, but I would appreciate an explanation from you as I don't understand why this could happen.

I created an `ol.source.Cluster` for the first geojson layer and referred the source of that `ol.layer.Vector` layer to that Cluster source:

```
var schoolCluster = new ol.source.Cluster({
    source:new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'Schools.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    })
});

var Schools = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: schoolCluster,
    style: iconStyleSchools
  });
```

But somehow it only works to get the properties when I refer the source directly in the vector layer without any cluster like this:

```
var Schools = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source:new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'Schools.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    }),
    style: iconStyleSchools
  });
```

With this code I could get all the properties I wanted from the geojson file and didn't get any `undefined` anymore. Could someone explain why?